# Codeigniter radio buttons

Tags: php, codeigniter, radio-button

I have CodeIgniter project and in my view file radio buttons selection.

If anyone has an idea how controller can know whitch button is selected?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Do you have any attemp of code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use same name for all radio button. Like the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_sex" id="radmale" class="css-checkbox" value="Male" />
<input type="radio" name="radio_sex" id="radfemale" class="css-checkbox" value="Female" />
```

Now from controller you can easily get the selected radio button's value by using the following code:

```
$this->input->post('radio_sex');
```

Thats all.